# Force image magick identify to show output size in MB

Tags: imagemagick

If I run for example

```
>identify test_img_2.png
```

I get

```
>test_img_2.png PNG 256x256 256x256+0+0 16-bit sRGB 371KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

Is it possible with some options to output the size in MB?
Reading through `man identify` there's the `format` option, but I'm not sure how to use it.

Thank you.

Comment: There is no control over that. And different versions of Imagemagick may show different units (B, KB, MB, etc). But you can do your own computations as Mark Setchell shows below. The %[fx:extent] gives you the file size in bytes without showing the B, so that it is totally numeric. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mebibyte for the difference between MB and MiB. Mark computes MiB below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this but it will output zero for small files:

```
identify -format "%[fx:int(extent/(1024*1024))]"  image.jpg
```

So, if I create a big file:

```
convert -size 10000x10000 xc:red +noise random a.jpg
```

Check the size with `ls`:

```
ls -l a.jpg
-rw-r--r--@ 1 mark  staff  174312876  4 Feb 17:51 a.jpg
```

Check with `identify` in MB:

```
identify -format "%[fx:int(extent/(1024*1024))]"  a.jpg
166
```

Or include the filename too:

```
identify -format "%f: %[fx:int(extent/(1024*1024))]"  a.jpg
a.jpg: 166
```

If you want to include other info, look [here](https://imagemagick.org/script/escape.php) at the list of available information.

---

Note that if you are using **ImageMagick** v7 or newer, that becomes:

```
magick identify ...
```